# Create a dynamic grid or table using positions x,y from an object in controller - bootstrap, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I am having a lot of trouble to create a dynamic table or a grid using positions provided by objects and I don't know if I am very bad at searching but I am not finding a solution on google.

The thing is that i have those objects on a controller:

```
$scope.stacks = [{
    'id': 1,
    'rid': [1, 3, 7, 9],
    'power': 'On',
    'x': '1',
    'y': '1'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'rid': [2, 12, 10, 6],
    'power': 'Off',
    'x': '1',
    'y': '2'
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'rid': [4, 5, 11, 8],
    'power': 'Off',
    'x': '1',
    'y': '3'
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'rid': [13, 14, 15, 16],
    'power': 'Off',
    'x': '1',
    'y': '4'
  }, {
    'id': 5,
    'rid': [17, 18],
    'power': 'Off',
    'x': '2',
    'y': '1'
  }
]
```

Regarding position x and y I want to be able to set each object positions and using ng-repeat, for now let's say that I just want to display a button with the stack id but at the right place using the x,y positions.

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="myStack in stacks">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn3-success btn-lg btn3d"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> {{myStack.id}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to link the positions to the HTML (meaning that you have 1,2 positions so you will be set at line 1 column 2), can someone please help me ? I am struggling here and can not think that no one has ever tried to do something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform your array into a list of rows, where each row has a list of cells.

The transformation function:

```
function transformToRows(stacks) {
    var ordered = $filter('orderBy')(stacks, '\'x\'');
    var rows = [];

    var maxRows = ordered[ordered.length-1].x;
    var maxCells = 0;
    angular.forEach(ordered, function(item) {
      if (item.y > maxCells)
        maxCells = item.y;
    });    


    for (let i = 0; i < maxRows; ++i) {
      var row = { index: i, cells: [] };
      rows.push(row);
       for (let j = 0; j < maxCells; ++j)
         row.cells.push({ index: j, data: undefined });
    }

    angular.forEach(ordered, function(item) {
       var row = rows[item.x-1];
       row.cells[item.y-1].data = item;
    });    
    return rows;
}
```

This will transform your array into the following:

```
[{ index: 0, 
   cells: [ 
       { index: 0, data: {...} }, 
       { index: 0, data: {...} }] 
  }, 
  { index: 1, 
    cells: [ 
       { index: 0, data: {...} }] 
    },
    ...
]
```

The `data`  property of the cell contains your stack.

Then you can render the rows and the cells in a table using ngRepeat:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells">
      {{ cell.data.power }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Demo Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6bdDJkXzwOkiZkcud7Iz?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much for responding quickly, I can not test it now but I will do it tomorrow, but it seems to be exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: I just tested it on the plunker, I changed my array as you said or I think but it is not working, I edited the plunker, I am not writing the array correctly ? [link to plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ygn5DlddfPdHrjXEkHQG?p=preview)

Comment: No, leave your original array the way it was. Check out the plnkr I provided.

Comment: Yes i checked it but it is not working, all i get in the result is : `{{ rows }}
{{ cell.data.power }}`

Comment: The plnkr I provided is working... Are you sure you're doing the same thing?

Comment: Well in the result i should get a tab listing the power so on off off off right ? In the page result i only get this : `{{ rows }} {{ cell.data.power }}` I am just looking at the plunker you provided without modifying anything. And my mistake by looking again at your response i understand now why i don't have to change my array, but still I don't know why it is not working then...

Comment: Ok after testing it in my code directly i found the problem, in the transformation function in the for loop you were initializing the i and j variable using a "let variable" which does not exist, I replaced it by "var" and it is working perfectly ! I edited the plnkr [link to plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SGBHIa3cSIUkilL7JZU7?p=preview) ! Thank you very much this solution is perfect and also elegant, not too much code :)